# How to group by only year in DQL?

Tags: sql, symfony

How can I translate this query to Doctrine Query Language

```
SELECT year(created), count(*) as newusers 
from `user` 
group by year(created);
```

Comment: What is "*doctine*", exactly?

Comment: Doctrine(PHP Symfony ORM)

Comment: Do you mean how to write this query in Doctrine Query Language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your query only needs to group by year from a datetime column, you will need the YEAR function, which is not supported by default in DQL. You can install [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) which will add the functionality you need.

```
composer require beberlei/DoctrineExtensions
```

And then edit the doctrine config file (config/packages/doctrine.yaml) as follow:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions: 
                YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Postgresql\Year
```

Now you will be able to write your request like this in your UserRepository

```
public function yearGroup(){
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('COUNT(u) as newusers, YEAR(u.created) as year')
        ->groupBy('year')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```